Adding IFR to an Experimental
I am considering buying an Experimental-Amateur Built plane. It was originally equipped and approved for VFR only.
The second owner completely redid the avionics, and it’s now a solid IFR platform and fully compliant with 91.205(d) as far as I can tell, but they never got the Operating Limitations updated to allow IFR.
What all is involved in correcting that oversight?
